# how to remove buttons created dynamically

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create number of `Button`s *dynamically* by giving the range in a `TextBox`.

The Problem is that when i enter the range e.g (3). It creates 3 buttons but then when i give the range less than the range given before e.g (2). it does not show me 2 buttons it shows me the previous 3 buttons. My code works for the range greater than the previous range but it fails when the new range is less than the previous range.

Here is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
    Button[] textBoxes = new Button[number];
    int location = 136;

    for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++)
    {
        location += 81;
        var txt = new Button();
        textBoxes[i] = txt;
        txt.Name = "text" + i.ToString();
        txt.Text = "textBox" + i.ToString();
        txt.Location = new Point(location, 124);
        txt.Visible = true;
        this.Controls.Add(txt);
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are giving a name like `textBoxes` to your `Button` array?

Comment: first i wanted to create textboxes. so i forgot to change the names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't removing the previous controls. You have to store them in an array then removing them before creating the new ones:

```
class Form1 : Form {
    private Button[] _textBoxes;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        int number = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        if(_textBoxes != null) {
            foreach(Button b in _textBoxes)
                this.Controls.Remove(b);
        }

        _textBoxes = new Button[number];
        int location = 136;

        for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++) {
            location += 81;
            var txt = new Button();
            _textBoxes[i] = txt;
            txt.Name = "text" + i.ToString();
            txt.Text = "textBox" + i.ToString();
            txt.Location = new Point(location, 124);
            txt.Visible = true;
            this.Controls.Add(txt);
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

it is not fail, what is happening is overlap previous buttons you created.

Comment: yeah but how to remove that overlping.

Answer (score 0):

first remove the buttons already there. you can keep track of them by keeping a pattern in their names or having global list etc or in other way. when ever you enter in function, remove all the buttons present before and create then new ones.